# I have an Expandable ListView in my app whose child has webView and I have to load a pdf file from my assets folder in to this webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, expandablelistview

My MainActivity sends some list of values to Expandable List adapter which have to be loaded in my parent view and child view

This is my getChildView code

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_1, null);
    }

    // WebView webViewChild = (WebView) convertView
    // .findViewById(R.id.webViewAarti);
    // webViewChild.loadUrl(childText);
    CopyReadAssets(childText);
    return convertView;

}
```

childText gives us the pdf file name.

I have used existing answers in stackoverflow to load a pdf file from assets but everything loads as new Activity with the help of intent in a full screen but I want to load it in my childView's webview. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Since when can a WebView display a pdf?

Comment: I have no clue dude, thats my requirement. If we are not able to show in a webView I can just add a layout and I am okay to display a pdf file in that childview

Comment: Then please tell which other layout/view can do that.

Comment: are you helping me out or inturn asking me questions? I didnt get you actually.

Comment: You should have known by now that what you want is impossible.

Comment: Cool, Sarcasm is not encouraged here you should have mentioned directly. Thanks for the reply by the way dude.

Comment: Try this https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/. It is possible indeed thanks to the mozilla pdf.js

Comment: I think the requirement comes from the fact that a simple way to display a pdf in iOS is to have the webview load and show it for you. If you are porting an iOS app I would skip the webview part and try to use some android native libraries to handle the pdf.